# can i ActionResult as [HttpGet] and JsonReult as [HttpPost]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

is my JsonResult Part true?
is it possible [HttpGet] be ActionResult and [HttpPost] be JsonReult? and have diffrent names?
 i think i'm wrong in my controller.it dose not work .

Mycontroller:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Customer()
    {
        var obj = new Project.Models.CentricModelClasses.ViewModelX();
        return PartialView(obj);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(ViewModelX jsonMyModel)
    {
        var result = true;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

          result= MyClass.Insert (jsonMyModel.Address, jsonMyModel.Cod,
                jsonMyModel.idpurchase,
                jsonMyModel.idspend, jsonMyModel.Lname,
                jsonMyModel.Name, jsonMyModel.Tell, jsonMyModel.username);

        }
        else
        {

        }

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

my class :

```
     public class ViewModelX
     {
    public Nullable< long > idpurchase { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> idspend { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public string Tell { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string CodPosti { get; set; }

    }
```

partail view :

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.username)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Tell)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Mobil)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Lname)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.id_purchase)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.id_spend) 

   <script type="text/javascript">

$("#submit-btn2").click(function () { saveMyModel();});

function SaveMyModel()
{
    var e = document.getElementById("id_purchase");
    var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var e2 = document.getElementById("id_spend");
    var str2 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            jsonMyModel: {

                username: $(".tdBuyername").val(),
                Tell: $(".tdPhone").val(),
                Name: $(".tdRecievername").val(),
                Mobil: $(".tdMobile").val(),
                Lname: $(".tdLname").val(),

                id_purchase: $("# id_purchase ").val(str),
                id_spend: $("# id_spend ").val(str2),
            }

            })
    });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work'. Please expand oh *what* does not work.

Comment: i mean my all model's field are passed null

Comment: You've tagged this question with three different versions of the MVC framework. Which one are you using?

Comment: neontapir , i use mvc4

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the jQuery selectors you are using. This (`username: $(".tdBuyername").val(),` is using a class selector, so will look for any elements with a class of `tdBuyername`. Likely you actually want id or name.

ID - `$("#tdBuyername").val()`

Name - `$("[name=tdBuyername]").val()`

Also make sure yor JSON objects property names match the model you are trying to bind to. e.g. `idpurchase` won't be populated by the property `id_purchase` being posted back.

But, to the other question you asked, about whether your save method is correct, I would say it needs some minor improvements. Maybe like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Save(ViewModelX jsonMyModel)
{
    var result = false; //default to false in case Model isn't valid

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      result= MyClass.Insert (jsonMyModel.Address, jsonMyModel.Cod,
            jsonMyModel.idpurchase,
            jsonMyModel.idspend, jsonMyModel.Lname,
            jsonMyModel.Name, jsonMyModel.Tell, jsonMyModel.username);
    }

    return Json(result);
}
```